# Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на разные кнопки на 1 контроллере, производились разные расчёты, и на 2 контроллере отображались разные значения в label

Tags: swift, передача-данных

У меня на одном контроллере несколько кнопок, на другом - 3 label. Когда на первом VC нажимаю на одну из кнопок, производятся расчёты и передаются данные по segue с идентификатором, на первом экране эти данные раскладываются в button.text

Когда же нажимаю на другую кнопку - планируется точно такой же алгоритм, только другие вычисления, другие данные, другой идентификатор segue, нужно передать данные и отобразить их в тех же label

Попробовала так - понятно, что не вышло.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "showFirstDestiny" else {return}
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? DestinyTextViewController else { return }
    destination.skyNumber = sky
    destination.groundNumber = ground
    destination.firstDestinyNubder = firstDestiny
    
    
    guard segue.identifier == "showSecondDestiny" else {return}
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? DestinyTextViewController else { return }
    destination.menNumber = men
    destination.womenNumber = women
    destination.secondDestinyNumber = secondDestiny
}
```

Проставила кнопкам tag. Получается вообще какая-то ерунда и сплошные ошибки, потому что просто беру готовое решение пятилетней давности и оно не работает. Как сделать, чтобы по  segue данные передавались при нажатии и на вторую кнопку, а потом отображались именно они в том же label?

Код второго контроллера

```
class DestinyTextViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var skyNumber = ""
    var groundNumber = ""
    var firstDestinyNubder = ""
    var menNumber = ""
    var womenNumber = ""
    var secondDestinyNumber = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var destiniLevelLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var destinySkyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyGroundLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyFirstLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyMenLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyWomenLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinySecondLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyFirstText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinySecondText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinyThirdText: UITextView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      
            destinyMenLabel.text = menNumber
            destinyWomenLabel.text = womenNumber
            destinySecondLabel.text = secondDestinyNumber
       
        destinySkyLabel.text = skyNumber
        destinyGroundLabel.text = groundNumber
        destinyFirstLabel.text = firstDestinyNubder
        
    }

}
```

Простите, но я совсем ещё ноль)) как это решить? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Покажите код обоих контроллеров (В сокращенной виде если нужно, оставив только необходимый код)

Comment: выложила весь второй контроллер, в первом очень много будет, там длинные вычисления с многократной конвертацией типов. До момента введения метода передачи данных всё исправно считает.

Comment: Получается первые три переменные отображаются как нужно, вторые три - просто пустые области, а должны быть данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас из-за условия `guard segue.identifier == "showFirstDestiny" else {return}` (одно означает: идентификатор должен быть равен "showFirstDestiny", иначе выйти из функции) выполнение никогда не доходит до `guard segue.identifier == "showSecondDestiny" else {return}`, попробуйте такой вариант

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? DestinyTextViewController else { return }
        
        switch segue.identifier {
        case "showFirstDestiny":
            destination.skyNumber = sky
            destination.groundNumber = ground
            destination.firstDestinyNubder = firstDestiny
            
        case "showSecondDestiny":
            destination.menNumber = men
            destination.womenNumber = women
            destination.secondDestinyNumber = secondDestiny
            
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
```

**Дополнение**

> Если дальше есть передача данных на другой UIViewController, это
> получается { return } там не подходит, а как тогда перейти к другому
> условию? Если например destination = segue.destination as?
> OTHERViewController

Можно сделать двумя способами - через `if let` или через `case let`

```
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DestinyTextViewController {
            switch segue.identifier {
            case "showFirstDestiny":
                //
                
            case "showSecondDestiny":
                //
                
            default:
                break
            }
        } else if let destination = segue.destination as? OtherViewController {
            // ...
        }
```

```
        switch segue.destination {
            
        case let destination as DestinyTextViewController:
            
            switch segue.identifier {
            case "showFirstDestiny":
                //
                
            case "showSecondDestiny":
                //
                
            default:
                break
            }
            
        case let destination as OtherViewController:
            print("other")
        
        default:
            break
            
        }
```

Comment: Ой! Спасибо огромное за отклик!!! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Боже! Храни stackoverflow! Всё работает! Что бы я без Вас делала? Точнее я бы оооочень долго догоняла! Спасибо ещё раз!!!

Comment: @КатаринаМалова на здоровье, поставьте галку возле ответа

Comment: Есть)) поставила

Comment: Простите, а можно тогда ещё попросить помощи в завершении этой задачки? Если дальше есть передача данных на другой UIViewController, это получается { return } там не подходит, а как тогда перейти к другому условию? Если например destination = segue.destination as? OTHERViewController ?

Comment: @КатаринаМалова см дополнение

Comment: Посмотрела, сделала, вроде всё работает! Спасибо!!!